# Debug karate features in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, karate

I have test

```
  @Test
  public void myTest() {
    Results results = Runner.path("classpath:features/myFeature.feature").parallel(1);
    Assert.assertEquals(results.getErrorMessages(), 0, results.getFailCount());
  }
```

Feature looks like this

```
 * def myVariable =
    """
    function(x, y)
    {
        functionBody...
    }
    """

 Scenario: My scenario
     * kafkaClient.publish(...)
     * def result = myVariable(...)
     And assert result != null
```

I installed karate plugin, now in feature I see the syntax highlighting, however there is no ability to put breakpoint in feature.

I use karate version 1.2.0

How I can debug features? I want to stop at (* def result) line for example, or I want to debug js function (functionBody...). Is there any proper way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you can debug a feature file if you use the run-configuration as shown in this video: https://youtu.be/w6V8rKOtyyg

We don't yet support debugging in JS blocks.

You need to be on the paid version of the plugin for feature-file debugging to work.

Comment: that's not good ((

Comment: @liotur we are always open to feedback, please let us know which is important for you and we will prioritize that

Comment: Price is too high for such obvious and needed thing as debug. Debug should be free IMO :)